# Qt resources loads empty .js files

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I am having a problem loading javascript files into qt resources.
My res.qrc is as follows:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>mapl.js</file>
        <file>mapl.html</file>
        <file>qwebchannel.js</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In mapl.html I am using the script load tag from resources:

```
   <script src="qrc:///qwebchannel.js"></script>
   <script src="qrc:///mapl.js"></script>
```

However, the files were not uploaded properly.
I am trying to load mapl.js file as follows:

```
QFile file(":/mapl.js");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QString dump = file.readAll();
    qDebug() << "contents: " << dump;
} else {
    qDebug() << "error: " << file.error();
}
```

The result of executing this code is an empty string: contents: "".
If I use this code to load mapl.html, it returns all page text.
I used various text editors to create javascript files, but this gives no result.
I also tried to rename my mapl.js to mapl.txt and load it from c++. The result returned me a string with the contents.
It seems to work with any file types other than .js
What could be the problem?

I am using qt 5.13 and the Visual Studio 2017 compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have `CONFIG += qtquickcompiler` in your `.pro` file. 
Either:

- disable Qt Quick Compiler from your `.pro` file if you do not use it
- or move resources which you don't want to be compiled, to another `.qrc` and add this line to your `.pro` file

```
QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES += bundle_only.qrc
```

Read [Qt Quick Compiler](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I used QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES + = bundle_only.qrc and this solved my problem. Now js is loading properly.